# How do you load and use a custom font in Svelte

Tags: fonts, svelte

I know it probably uses @font-face but I dont know where to put my woff files localy to get Svelte to use a custom font. I dont know where to put the @font-face either. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Svelte doesn't require anything special to use fonts.

You can inline a `@font-face` in your stylesheet or inside any `.svelte` file's `<style>` tag:

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Gelasio';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: local('Gelasio Regular'), local('Gelasio-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/gelasio/v1/cIf9MaFfvUQxTTqS9C6hYQ.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: Gelasio
    }
</style>
```

Alternatively, you can include the font with a `<link>` inside the head. For this approach `<svelte:head>` is handy:

```html
<svelte:head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gelasio" rel="stylesheet">
</svelte:head>
```

Comment: Works for me: https://svelte.dev/repl/8ea0c71d1d2043da8186909afd864aba?version=3.18.2

Comment: I get the feeling that local font files (vs locally installed fonts) are treated differently. For example if you had used `src: url('cIf9MaFfvUQxTTqS9C6hYQ.woff2')` with the font as a local file in the svelte directory, it wouldn't have worked. When Eddysanoli says "where to put my woff files locally" I assume this is what they mean. I should clarify I only meant your main solution doesn't work— the <svelte:head> alternative you wrote certainly does work.

Comment: The examples above do not answer, "where to put my woff files locally". They are examples of using locally installed TrueType or OpenType fonts or using URLs to access fonts hosted by Google. If WOFF files are going to be hosted on the site, they need to go in the static folder. It gets more complicated if the site being deployed is not the root domain.

Comment: Anybody knows how to make this work with a dynamic font url. I have this project where a component displays a font. So it needs to have its own @font-face. But style tags cannot take variable interpolation afaik. I have tried to set css vars on the style tag but it does not seem to work either.

Comment: @Mig a stylesheet can be created dynamically with JS and inserted into the DOM.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/CSSStyleSheet#examples

Comment: Ah thanks @joshnuss ! I ended up doing something similar. I have realised you can create font face declarations from javascript. I did this on onMount and it works fine. Same thing really except I create a specific font face object instead of a css object.

Answer (score 38):

If you are using Sveltekit, you can load fonts locally using the `static` directory.

Store your font files under `static/fonts`, and then use either a CSS file or a `<style>` tag to reference your font files.

```css
/* fonts.css */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('/fonts/lora-v20-latin-500.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local(''), url('/fonts/lora-v20-latin-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        /* IE6-IE8 */ url('/fonts/lora-v20-latin-500.woff2') format('woff2'),
        /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/lora-v20-latin-500.woff') format('woff'),
        /* Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/lora-v20-latin-500.ttf') format('truetype'),
        /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('/fonts/lora-v20-latin-500.svg#Lora') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Finally, just import the CSS file in your `__layout.svelte` file:

```html
<!-- __layout.svelte -->

<script lang="ts">
    import '/styles/fonts.css';
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if you got it to work already but make sure your custom fonts are placed somewhere in the `/public` folder and not in `/src`.

So if you place them in `/public/fonts` you can simply access them in your `global.css`
with:

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: 'yourFont';
  src: url('/fonts/yourFont.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: If not working, then rerun dev. (`npm run dev`)

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
<svelte:head>
    <style>
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap");
    </style>
</svelte:head>
```

Answer (score 7):

I did it like this: I downloaded the font, put it in static folder.
Then, in index.html, I added this style tag:

```html
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                src: url('%sveltekit.assets%/open-sans-v27-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
            }
        </style>
```

And in +layout.svelte, I added this:

```html
<style global>
    body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this has something to do with https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/904 - current workaround : use relative path to the font files.