# Use carbon-components-svelte without internet access Fonts issue

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, carbon-components-svelte

I am using this component to build a GUI and automatically download all fonts from [https://1.www.s81c.com](https://stackoverflow.com), but in my scenario the GUI should be standalone an from where is running, there is not internet access, so is not able to download those fonts.

There is some configuration to get them some other way or if not, where should place the fonts inside the project to fix this issue?

Also even trying to download the fonts and use them locally, is trying to download them with all console logs errors

Thanks

I tried to set the fonts inside static or public folder and access to them from app.css:

`@font-face { font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono'; src: local("IBM Plex Mono Light"), url('/fonts/IBMPlexMono-Light-Latin1.woff2') format('woff2'); }`

But I need to do this for more than 10 fonts and now is also getting an error about downloaded font

`Failed to decode downloaded font`

Comment: You can download them, add them to your static folder and load them locally. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400854/911192

Answer (score 0):

There is [a currently open issue](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/issues/1593) regarding the hard-coded fonts. You could pre-process the CSS files with a build plugin to download the fonts and reference them locally.

There are links to implementations of this logic in the linked issue which you might be able to use, or you can write your own, it is not that complicated.